# [Python][Moviepy] How to add a short silence in the end of an audio?

Tags: python, audio, moviepy

I'd like to include a short silence duration at the end of an audio clip. I haven't found any specific functions in the Moviepy documentation, so I've resorted to creating a muted audio file of 500ms and concatenating it with the original audio file.

In some cases, this concatenation will introduce a noticeable glitch at the intersection, and I haven't figured out why. I also realized by importing the concatenated audiofile to Audacity that Moviepy actually creates two audio tracks when concatenating.

Do you know a better way to add silence to the end of the clip, or maybe the reason why this glitch appears sometimes (in my experience about 1 every 4 instances)?

Here's my code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

temp_audio = "original audio dir"
silence = "silence audio dir"

audio1 = AudioFileClip(temp_audio)                      #original audio file
audio2 = AudioFileClip(silence)                         #silence audio file
final_audio = concatenate_audioclips([audio1,audio2])
final_audio.write_audiofile(output)
```

I am currently using Python 3.9.5 and Moviepy 1.0.3

Comment: You can create an `AudioClip`, passing in a function that just returns 0

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could do that! I tried it but unfortunately I still get the same audio glitch. Here's the code I used: silence = AudioClip(make_frame = lambda t: 0, duration = 0.5, fps = 24 ). Then I concatenated like in my previous code. Maybe the problem is the concatenating function then

Comment: It seems that using ffmpeg directly fixes the audio glitch, so I'll be using it for now:
os.system('ffmpeg -i "concat:'+temp_audio+'|'+silence+'" '+output)

Comment: Yes, ffmpeg is much better for simple concatenations :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when working with Moviepy with audio files.
Moviepy added "click" ("glitch") to some audio files.
I experimented and found out that the problem is not in the concatenate_audioclips or CompositeAudioClip functions, as I first thought.
*The problem is in the Moviepy AudioFileClip function.*

Even at the beginning, when reading some audio files and creating an audio clip, Moviepy adds a click to the end of the file.
I found and tested it like this:

```
audioclip = mp.AudioFileClip("audio.mp3")
audioclip.write_audiofile("test.mp3")
```

already here a "click" ("glitch") appears at the end, lasting about 0.1 second.

Probably the Moviepy **AudioFileClip function is broken :(**

**I solved the problem simply:** I had to cut off the last 0.15 seconds at the end of all my audio clips (it’s good that there is a little silence at the end)

```
audioclip = audioclip.subclip(0,-0.15)
```

*And only after that concatenate them.* Everything works well - no "glitchs" left.

Of course, this is all very unpleasant and took up my time.
Unfortunately I need Moviepy to merge video and audio and video editing.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use the below solution for adding the silence at the end or start of audio:**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
orig_seg = AudioSegment.from_file('audio.wav')
silence_seg = AudioSegment.silent(duration=1000) # 1000 for 1 sec, 2000 for 2 secs

# for adding silence at the end of audio
combined_audio = orig_seg + silence_seg

# for adding silence at the start of audio
#combined_audio = silence_seg + orig_seg

combined_audio.export('new_audio.wav', format='wav')
```

Answer (score 0):

may be fps=44100
will work . mp3 file's frequence

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).