# audio issues when merging a video with an audio file using python ffmpeg and moviepy

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, moviepy

I’m trying to create a code that syncs between an audio file and a background file in terms of duration.
When creating the merged video I hear a cut or a loop sound of the last sentence for like 0.2 seconds.
I have tried to solve it in many different ways, listed below.

Has anyone solved this issue? I saw many people having a similar problem.
I’m using Ubuntu version 20.04 and ffmpeg version 4.2.7

This is my code:

```py
def merge_videos_with_subs(
    background_path, audio_path, subs, output_directory, output_filename
):
    try:
        # Load background video and audio
        background_clip = VideoFileClip(background_path)
        background_clip = background_clip.without_audio()
        audio_clip = AudioFileClip(audio_path)

        # Adjust video duration to match audio duration
        audio_duration = audio_clip.duration

        # If the background video is longer, trim it to match the audio duration
        if background_clip.duration > audio_duration:
            background_clip = background_clip.subclip(0, audio_duration)
        # If the audio is longer, loop the background video
        else:
            background_clip = background_clip.loop(duration=audio_duration)

        # Set audio of the background clip
        background_clip = background_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)

        # Overlay subtitles on the video
        final_clip = CompositeVideoClip(
            [background_clip, subtitles.set_pos(("center", "bottom"))]
        )

        # Ensure the output directory exists
        os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

        # Define the output path
        output_path = os.path.join(output_directory, output_filename)

        # Write the merged video with subtitles
        final_clip.write_videofile(
            output_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", threads=4, fps=24
        )

        # Close the clips
        final_clip.close()
        background_clip.close()
        audio_clip.close()

        print(f"Merged video with subtitles saved to: {output_path}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error merging videos: {e}")
```

I’ve tried changing the codec, tried cutting 0.2 seconds of the audio before and after the merge or silencing it, nothing seems to help.
When I run my code without the background subclip to match the audio it worked flawlessy.
If I let the background run until its full duration or make it loop there were no audio issues.
Looks like the issue is on the cutting part.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the file, remove the glitch at the end. This is a bug in the Moviepy library.

```
audioclip = audioclip.subclip(0,-0.15)
```

I got the solution from this question.
[[Python][Moviepy] How to add a short silence in the end of an audio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67467995/pythonmoviepy-how-to-add-a-short-silence-in-the-end-of-an-audio)